# How to extract lines from text file, only when lines begins with date

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I got a log file that I have to transform into data file.
My file looks like :

```
Source: XXXXX
Target: XXXXX

Number of Objects Copied: 4
Size: 75▒131▒833
Start Time: juil. 10, 2019 02:13:30 PM
End Time: juil. 10, 2019 02:19:54 PM


Code XXXXX
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Following XXXXXXXX

HashMap Name   HashMap Id   HashMap Type
```

---

I want only the line begins with 07/10/19 02:19:54 PM (that can be another date its a log file and will be edited all days)

```
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
```

And put this lines into another file.

I try something like

```
while read line 
do 

  if [ $line == ['date +%Y%m%d']]
        then
        cat "$line\n" >> MY_DATA_FILE
        fi

done < MY_FILE_IN
```

But I cant match the regex with a date pattern

Comment: You can't match a regex because there's no regex in your code. If you don't need the dates to be validated you can reduce all the script to a single command: `grep -E "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"  MY_FILE_IN > MY_DATA_FILE`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I also tried a grep solution but I couldn't make `{}` work (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD). Any idea ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier yep, I forgot the `-E` switch. I fixed my original comment. Oh, I'm using GNU grep

Comment: `-E` also works with my grep version thanks

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

You can't match a regex because there's no regex in your code. If you don't need the dates to be validated you can reduce all the script to a single command:

```
grep -E "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}" MY_FILE_IN > MY_DATA_FILE
```

Comment: This is more precise than the `awk`-approach and probably less ressource intensive as firing up an interpreter (like awk).

Comment: `grep` can be further sped up here with `-x` for matching entire lines and adding `.*` to the end of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick:

```
$ grep -E '^([0-9]{2}[ :/]){6}' file
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX

$ grep '^\([0-9]\{2\}[ :/]\)\{6\}' file
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX

$ sed -En '/^([0-9]{2}[ :/]){6}/p' file
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX

$ sed -n '/^\([0-9]\{2\}[ :/]\)\{6\}/p' file
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX

$ awk '/^([0-9]{2}[ :/]){6}/' file
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk :

```
awk '/^[0-9 \/:]{17}/' <file>
```

Output :

```
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE  DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:19:54 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
07/10/19 02:15:53 PM  XX TABLE DATA COMPLETE XX
```

Of course, to write on another file, use this :

```
awk '/^[0-9 \/:]{17}/' <input> > <output>
```

Comment: @Sandra honestly I'd prefer the grep solution as this tool exists for this exact purpose.